# jquery.js 9557 error in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, syntax-error

This is my function where I need to make a response in ajax

```
function load_id_user(id) {
    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    alert(id);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'load-user',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN,id:id},
        success: function (data) {
           $( "#user_fields" ).html( data );
        }
    });
}
```

this is my route.

```
Route::post('load-user','UserController@load_id');
```

and this is my controller

```
public function load_id() {
    $var=DB::select('select * from user where user_id="$_POST[id]"');

    //$var=Usuarios::select()->where("user_id","=",$_POST['id'])->get();
    foreach ($var as $user) {
        echo '<input type="text" name="cedula" value="'.$user->user_id.'" onblur="load_id_user(this.value);" placeholder="Cedula" class="form-control" required>';
    }
}
```

when I try to run this the console say error 500, try everything and nothing works.

Comment: Check the html section to get the actual error text

Comment: Have you tried accessing the id using the request object? `public function load_id(Request $request) { $id = $request->input('id')` ?

Comment: I think it's a bug in the back-end but nothing appears in the html was the first thing I check

Comment: Show some error messages. http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/1255289

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your controller code to

```
public function load_id (Request $request) {

    $id = $request->input('id');
    $response = '';

    $var = Usuarios::where("user_id", "=", $id)->get();

    foreach ($var as $user) {
        $response .= '<input type="text" name="cedula" value="'.$user->user_id.'" onblur="load_id_user(this.value);" placeholder="Cedula" class="form-control" required>';
    }

    return $response;
}
```

and your ajax request to

```
$.ajax({
    url: window.location.origin + '/load-user',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
        id:id
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $( "#user_fields" ).html( data );
    }
});
```

Comment: When you check out the html response in the console can you figure out the error?

Comment: no i can because only say POST http..... error 500 (internal server error)

Comment: When you click on that POST http, on the right side of the console you'll be able to see the response from the server

Comment: it say Jquery.js 9557

Comment: go to network tab and not console, then try the ajax call, a red request will apear and will tell you what's going on, it would be probably route not found, try adding this `url: '/load-user'`. (the / )